# Any issues with computer on one domain in a separate forest and user account in another domain/forest?

Tags: user-accounts, active-directory

I have a few of my sites with a trust relationship among two different forests with a single domain in each AD forest.

I'll skip all the politics and details that don't matter and just ask the question:

**Will having a machine with a computer account in one domain and their user account in another cause any issues?**

*(besides GPO behavior that would need to be understood such as their computer getting a GPO applied from the computer's domain, and their user account getting a GPO applied from their user domain)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you have the trust setup properly you should be all good. The one thing to watch out for is you can only put user objects from trusted domains into certain type of groups - Universal and Domain Local groups IIRC, there may be a few other limitations I'm forgetting though.

Comment: What Zypher said. Have fun with cross-forest GPO processing! :)